# hana::second can't deduce type

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, boost-hana

I'm trying to access a `hana::type` from a pair using `hana::second`...

```
namespace hana = boost::hana;
using namespace hana::literals;

struct Key {};
struct Foo {};

int main() {

  auto test = hana::make_tuple(
      hana::make_pair(
        hana::type_c<Key>, 
        hana::type_c<Foo>));

  typename decltype(hana::type_c<Foo>)::type  finalTest; //Ok
  typename decltype(hana::second(test[0_c]))::type finalTest2; //Error
}
```

But I am getting the following compiler error:

```
stacktest.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
stacktest.cpp:17:12: error: decltype evaluates to ‘boost::hana::type_impl<Foo>::_&’, which is not a class or enumeration type
   typename decltype(hana::second(test[0_c]))::type finalTest2;
```

Why does the result of `hana::second` not return the contained `hana::type` as expected?

Comment: I downvoted because this is Stack Overflow and not What's App - Please be more formal in your titles and remove inappropriate language like "_wtf_"

Comment: Could you please paste the error message and tell us what is the result you expect?

Comment: What error do you get?  Do `boost::tuple`'s have a `operator[]`?

Comment: I hate it when my compiler provides an error message like `//Error` that it inlines into the code.  So hard to figure out.

Comment: You're right I should have been more explicit about the error sorry

Comment: @Roberto Well I just want it to compile, the error is a variable declaration.

Comment: The problem is that `hana::second` returns a reference to the contained value. You can wrap it in `hana::typeid_(...)` to get a `hana::type` with ref qualifiers stripped. This could be a good question perhaps if it was formatted a little better.

Comment: @JasonRice I'm not sure if it was just because I didn't really understood the problem or if I was just too ashamed to ask it sorry. Didn't know about hana::typeid_ thought thanks :)

Comment: @KyleKhalaf I would like to edit and answer the question if that is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message states that the decltype is evaluating to `boost::hana::type_impl<Foo>::_&`, which while a little cryptic looking, you can see by the `&` at the end that it is a **reference** to the contained `hana::type`. Unfortunately the reference will not contain the members that you expect to find in the raw type.

For this `hana::type` provides a unary `operator+` that simply dereferences to the raw type so you can do the following:

```
typename decltype(+hana::second(test[0_c]))::type finalTest2;
```

`hana::typeid_` works for this as well as it idempotently wraps any value in a `hana::type` with const and reference qualifiers stripped:

```
typename decltype(hana::typeid_(hana::second(test[0_c])))::type finalTest2;
```

It's worth noting that all of the following Hana functions return references:

`first`, `second`, `at`, `at_key`, and associated `operator[]`.

Comment: The unary operator + is working for me, but when I try to use `hana::typeid_` I get a compiler error that there is no `typeid_` found in namespace hana. Any idea why that would be? I have generically included <boost/hana.hpp> and I believe that I'm using the latest boost (assuming homebrew has the latest boost because I'm fairly sure cmake is linking against the brew copy). Was this function added or removed at a certain point?

Comment: It was added in Boost 1.62. https://github.com/boostorg/hana/commit/edbbffeea4c1b118f4d634098dfa7ec2faa0f95d