# How to retrieve types from boost::hana::tuple_t?

Tags: c++, boost-hana

I have using `hana:tuple_t` to store and retrieve a typelist:

```
auto Types = hana::tuple_t<int, double>;
auto first_t = Types[hana::int_c<0>];
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(first_t)::type, int>); // line 3
```

The above code, works correctly, however when I tried to replace the variable `first_t` by its actual expression:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(Types[hana::int_c<0>])::type, int>); //line 4
```

I get a compile error:

```
template argument 1 is invalid
     static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(Types[hana::int_c<0>])::type, int>);
 error: decltype evaluates to ‘const boost::hana::type_impl<int>::_&’, which is not a class or enumeration type
```

Line 3 and Line 4 of the above code are equivalent, how come I get the compile error for line 4:

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618052/hanasecond-cant-deduce-type/43639764#43639764

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decltype(Types[hana::int_c<0>])` is a `const` reference to `boost::hana::type_impl<int>::_` and you cannot query a *reference* to get the `::type` from the reference***d*** type.

`first_t` is declared with just `auto`, and that removes the reference and the constness. If you wanted to keep that (in a different situation), you could declare it `auto & first_t = ...`.

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(first_t), boost::hana::type_impl<int>::_>);
```

You can use `std::decay_t` to get rid of the reference.

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<
    std::decay_t<decltype(Types[hana::int_c<0>])>::type, int>);
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks